# Find "x" greatest differences in Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, difference

Let's say I have a list of data... say stock prices for example, and I want to find out more about the differences between each element of the list - particularly the greatest differnece. In this case, it would be finding the 2 prices that exhibit the greatest change (i.e. greatest gain or loss).

Now, I don't simply want to find the *singular* greatest difference. I want to find maybe the 5 greatest differences - where all 5 pairs of numbers used to calculate the difference are unique and don't converge upon the same solution.

One way this could be done is with nested for loops like so:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in nums:
    for x in nums:
        return x-i
```

But I feel this method is really clunky and doesn't solve the question at hand. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Edit:

***Solution for those interested***

I used a modified version of @Chris_Rands answer to solve the problem. Basically, this function just finds the single greatest difference and then removes each element from the original list and does this process until only 1 element is left (when you can't find another diff). The result is an array of tuples containing 100% unique pairs of the greatest differences from the dataset:

```
from itertools import combinations
from heapq import nlargest

nums = [98,34,513,352,3523,308,13]

def findTrades(list_, amount):
    Trades_ = []

    while len(list_) >= 2:
        res = nlargest(1, combinations(list_, 2), key = lambda x: abs(x[0]-x[1]))
        Trades_.append(res)
        for i in res[0]:
            list_ = [x for x in list_ if x != i]

    return sorted(Trades_)[-amount:]

print (findTrades(nums, 3))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `x=3`. Using `heapq.nlargest` is better than sorting for small values of `x`.

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> from heapq import nlargest
>>> nlargest(3, combinations(nums, 2), key = lambda x: abs(x[0]-x[1]))
[(1, 5), (1, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Comment: I used this and it worked great! One question though...since there's a maximum in basically all datasets how could I get the greatest differences that only utilize the max once? Every pair of numbers would have to unique, the max couldn't be repeated down the line like 5 is here in this example.

Comment: @jblew Looks like you want just get the 5 largest and 5 smallest numbers, sort them, then get their differences that way.

Answer (score 2):

Take the [cartisean product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and use `max`:

```
from itertools import combinations 
nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
max(combinations(nums,2), key=lambda t: abs(t[0]-t[1]))
# (1,5)
```

If you want them sorted by difference:

```
sorted(combinations(nums,2), key=lambda t: abs(t[0]-t[1]), reverse=True)
[(1, 5), (1, 4), (2, 5), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: This works perfect! But how could I also make it only use the max and min once? In your 2nd example 5 and 1 are used repeatedly, is it possible to only use those values once so that every pair is made of completely unique values from nums? The result array would be significantly shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that takes a list / tuple and returns the 5 greatest differenced. Note this doesn't use any other dependencies other than the builtins.

Usage:
`differences(list_, length)`
`list_` is the input list that you want to check.
`length` is the number of differences you want to record.

```
def differences(list_, length):
    diffs = list(0 for _ in range(length))
    for i, j in enumerate(list_):
        for k in list_[i + 1:]:
            if max(j, k) - min(j, k) > min(diffs):
                diffs[0] = max(j, k) - min(j, k)
                diffs = sorted(diffs)
    return diffs
```

The greatest 5 will be what is returned. If there's only 3 items in a list which makes 3 differences, the last two will be 0 as you cannot get a negative difference with this code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
from operator import sub
from itertools import combinations

gen = sorted(set(abs(sub(*tup)) for tup in combinations(nums, 2)), reverse=True)

gen

[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Yes, you're right this outputs every possible difference. But it doesn't seem to pass along the explicit original values that were subtracted. I didn't specify this in the OP, my mistake, but that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through the list once and find the 3 largest numbers in the list and the 3 smallest numbers in the list. Find the differences between all of these numbers and take the 3 largest. This will be performant and ensure the you found the top 5 largest differences.

Comment: I will add it tomorrow, I am about to play basketball.

Comment: gotta get those hoops in

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Matrices:

```
l = np.array([1,2,3,4])
a = np.tile(l,(len(l),1))
a - a.T
```

[image]

This will give you the difference between every two pairs of elements. Now you can pick the largest n pairs.

`b.ravel()[np.argsort(b.ravel())][-4:]` will give you the largest 4 values

> array([1, 2, 2, 3])

Answer (score 0):

sol holds all the five greatest differences.
I replace the minimum difference every time while iterating. Should be simple to understand. 
(I have not checked for edge cases and other problems)

```
lis=[1,2,6,3,76,44,98,23,56,87,23,65,19,73]
sol=[0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(len(lis)):
  for j in range(len(lis)):
    if abs(lis[i]-lis[j])>min(sol):
      sol[sol.index(min(sol))]=lis[i]-lis[j]

print(sol)

#returned this [86, 97, 92, 96, 95]
```